# reload .lldbinit without reloading the app?

Tags: xcode, lldb

Is there a way to reload a .lldbinit file, without rebuilding the app?  Similar to what one can do with gdb as follows:

```
 source ~/.gdbinit
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `command source`.

```
(lldb) command source ~/.lldbinit
```

If you are loading a Python file,

```
(lldb) command script import ~/lldb/bbt.py
```

although note that you cannot re-import a function that you've already imported in an lldb debug session; when refining a python script you'll need to quit & restart the debugger to try new versions.

Comment: I just came across this answer whilst looking into why my .lldbinit file wasn't being read, and having tried to use "command source", I get an error saying it can't find the file even though it's there. Here is the output:

(lldb) command source ~/.lldbinit
error: Error reading commands from file .lldbinit - file not found.
Executing commands in '~/.lldbinit'.
This is running Xcode 5.0.2 on OSX10.9 (Mavericks)

Any clues?

Comment: In recent versions of lldb it is possible to delete and re-import python functions using `command script delete <command name>`. Using `lldb-1100.0.30.6`.